# Using gnu-efi to read file

Tags: c, filesystems, gnu-efi

can't find any documentation for programming EFI using "gnu-efi" library. Just one example that demonstrates standard "Hello, world!".
What exactly steps I need to do open and read file if I know that there are two FAT32 partitions?
What protocols I need to initialise?

Answer (score 0):

What about writing an [EFI shell script](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting)? I don't know what you are trying to do but if it is simple then it can be done more easily in a script.

Comment: No, i need C code. It is very simple, just for test, load some data (it can be image) and show it to user.